# How can i install back default xubuntu stuff

Tags: xubuntu

I just did a godly mistake by removing wine with

```
sudo apt-get remove wine*
```

And it just broke my system by removing allmost everything, even non wine related stuff. Its like i had windows 7 before with Aero UI then removed notepad somehow then i have got everything went back to Windows 98. Thats only way to i can explain current situation.

Edit: I found what has been uninstalled by checking apt logs
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VLxv0VGh
Can i just fix everything by reinstalling them back?

Answer (score 2):

You can install the desktop metapackage:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

This should bring back everything that was part of the default installation.